# Jackson deserializing issue

Tags: json, typescript, spring-boot, jackson

```
JSON.stringify(saveIntObject) returns data [{"id":1,"narration":"Opening Balance ","percentage":12,"valu.........
public void saveInterestTransactionDetails(@RequestBody interest_master[] AcOp) -- spring boot Back end it was working fine.
public void saveInterestTransactionDetails(@RequestBody SaveInterestBean saveInterestBean)

public class SaveInterestBean {
    Interest_calculation_Bean[] FormatedData;
}
```

**{"FormatedData":**[{"id":1,"narration":"Opening Balance ","percentage":12,"valu.........

it was not working.

expected result - array of objects but received as null

Comment: I believe Jackson expects camel case for fields

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FormatedData : by changing the  property name to small characters,  it solved the issue

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).